# How can I write data directly to an S3 bucket using my KMS Key?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kms

I am trying to write data directly from R to an S3 bucket but cannot figure out how I can pass my KMS Key for encryption.

I tried to use the aws.s3 package in the following way:

```
s3write_using(iris, FUN = write.csv,
          bucket = my_bucket,
          object = "iris",
          opts=list(headers = c('ssekms_key_id' = my_kms_key)))
```

where `my_bucket` and `my_kms_key` are the corresponding bucket and key, respectively. However, I always get an error saying "Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")): cannot open the connection". Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? How do you write data to S3?